# Retrieve matched document from nested array

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I'm trying to collect all objects in a nested array where the field `spec` equals `unknown`.

The structure per document is similar to this:

```
{
    "_id" :"5b1e73786f11e421956023c3",
    "subs" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "subrepo1",
            "files" : [ 
                {
                    "name" : ".....",
                    "spec" : "Unknown"
                }, 
                {
                    "name" : ".....",
                    "spec" : "Unknown"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name" : "subrepo2",
            "files" : [ 
                {
                    "name" : "file2",
                    "spec" : "Unknown"
                }, 
                {
                    "name" : ".....",
                    "spec" : "1234"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried the following but it doesn't work. I'm think this is in the right direction but i'm probably missing something important.

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {$match: {'subs.files.spec': 'Unknown'}},
    {$project: {
        'subs.files': {$filter: {
            input: '$subs.files',
            //as: 'subs.files',
            cond: {$eq: ['this.spec', 'FunSuite']}
        }},
        //_id: 0
    }}
])
```

The expected output would be: (so ONLY the files that have spec equals to Unknown (NOT the other ones)

```
{
    "_id" : "5b1e73786f11e421956023c3",
    "subs" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "subrepo1",
            "files" : [ 
                {
                    "name" : ".....",
                    "spec" : "Unknown"
                }, 
                {
                    "name" : ".....",
                    "spec" : "Unknown"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name" : "subrepo2",
            "files" : [ 
                {
                    "name" : "file2",
                    "spec" : "Unknown"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn Added the output to make it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [$filter aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/#exp._S_filter) operator which gives only the matched element from the array and escapes the other elements

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$subs"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "subs.name": "$subs.name",
      "subs.files": {
        $filter: {
          input: "$subs.files",
          as: "file",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$file.spec",
              "Unknown"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      subs: {
        $push: "$subs"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Above will give following output

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "subs": [
      {
        "files": [
          {
            "name": ".....",
            "spec": "Unknown"
          },
          {
            "name": ".....",
            "spec": "Unknown"
          }
        ],
        "name": "subrepo1"
      },
      {
        "files": [
          {
            "name": "file2",
            "spec": "Unknown"
          }
        ],
        "name": "subrepo2"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

You can check the result [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XB9EM8FrTdB)

And if you want to get the fields as in array then remove the [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) stage from the pipeline

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$subs"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "subs.name": "$subs.name",
      "subs.files": {
        $filter: {
          input: "$subs.files",
          as: "file",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$file.spec",
              "Unknown"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$subs.files"
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: "$subs.files"
    }
  }
])
```

Above will give following output

```
[
  {
    "name": ".....",
    "spec": "Unknown"
  },
  {
    "name": ".....",
    "spec": "Unknown"
  },
  {
    "name": "file2",
    "spec": "Unknown"
  }
]
```

Comment: This is not the same input data as given in the example, can you change it? (The output is fine)

Comment: @CaptainObvious I have the changed the input and ouput... Please check it again...

Comment: it seems to work; thanks. Can you also provide the query for your original output? The output only contains the files {name: ..., spec: ....} because I would like to have that as well. I'll accept if you include that one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: '$subs'
    },
    {
        $unwind: '$subs.files'
    },
    {
        $match: {
            'subs.files.spec': 'Unknown'
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: This also returns elements in the files array where the spec doesn't equals to unknown, which I don't want (see output)